# How to install packages php7.2-hash php7.2-openssl php7.2-pdo_mysql if they are not found by apt

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, installation, php-pdo, environment-emulation

How to install packages `php7.2-hash php7.2-openssl php7.2-pdo_mysql` if they are not found by apt.

`php7.2-hash php7.2-openssl php7.2-pdo_mysql`

```
root@sample:~# apt install php7.2-hash 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-hash
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-hash'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-hash'
```

```
root@sample:~# apt install php7.2-openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-openssl
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-openssl'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-openssl'
```

```
root@sample:~# apt install php7.2-pdo_mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-pdo_mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-pdo_mysql'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-pdo_mysql'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hash**

Hash is not PHP library. As of PHP 5.1.2, the Hash extension is bundled and compiled into PHP by default. [(source)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/hash.installation.php)

To check if hash is enabled in your PHP, you can run

```
$ php -i | grep -i hash
```

You will see something similar to

```
hash
hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512/224 sha512/256 sha512 sha3-224 sha3-256 sha3-384 sha3-512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost gost-crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b crc32c fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164 fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5 
MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support
phar.require_hash => On => On
```

**OpenSSL**

OpenSSL is not PHP library. If you need openssl support, you have to install OpenSSL in your system.

```
$ sudo apt install openssl
```

To check if openssl is enabled in your PHP, you can run

```
$ php -i | grep -i openssl
```

You will see something similar to

```
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.1.1f
libSSH Version => libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

**PDO: MySQL**

PDO and the PDO_SQLITE driver is enabled by default as of PHP 5.1.0. You may need to enable the PDO driver for your database of choice; consult the documentation for database-specific PDO drivers to find out more about that. [(source)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php)

If you want to enable PDO: MySQL, you have to install MySQL and php-mysql in your system.

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server php-mysql
```

To check if PDO for MySQL is enabled in your PHP, you can run

```
$ php -i | grep -i pdo
```

You will see something similar to

```
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite
pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```